# How to convert a PDF created with Apache FOP to XML or JSON?

Tags: xml, json, windows, pdf, xsl-fo

I do not really know what I need, but I need ideas, so I'll give all that I know.

There is a linux server, on the server side there is a web based database application created mostly in PHP/MySQL that keeps track of all the business relevant information, invoices, stocks, costumer data...

A few number of computers in the workshop have specialized applications (Windows OS) that create their logs as PDF reports that cannot be saved permanently trough the application interface. The reports can only be printed or deleted. I have found the files on those client machines that are being populated with data while the applications is running. I would like to automate the process of populating that data into the database on the server.

The application uses a XSL-FO schema file, programmaticly inserts the values and generates a PDF file  that can be printed or discarded from their own editor, or manually opened from the temp location and saved on some other place as a copy. According to some sources, XSL-FO can be used to generate an XML file, but I do not see any way how to make such a change. Apache FOP 1.0 is the engine used and some configuration files are visible, so if I could make a change in the configuration files that would result in creation of XML instead of PDF, that would solve most of my problems. Is there a way to do that?

If I change the config file renderer property from
`<renderer mime="application/pdf">`
to
`<renderer mime="application/xml">`
would I achieve my goal?

I have found some solutions, but need an advice which of them would work.

1. I may be able to create some simple script that would send the file to a specific folder on the server, and some server side, I presume php script that would convert the file to XML or JSON and parse out the relevant information and update the database.
2. I can use some simple (free) windows tool that could do the converting and parsing and send the text file formatted as XML or JSON to the server for further processing.
3. Use a virtual printer to create a PDF file copy in a predefined folder and using that file as the starting point for option 1 or option 2

Is there any other way? Can you suggest an application / api / lib / that could help me out here, or just give me a right method how to think about the problem.

Thank you

Comment: XSL-FO _is_ XML (in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format` namespace). Whatever you planned on doing with the converted XML, you should be able to do with the XSL-FO directly. You shouldn't have to do anything with the rendered PDFs.

Comment: I do not see how it could be possible. The XSL-FO is a file that defines the structure and page to page locations of various strings. The XLS-FO is programmaticly combined with real-time data to create the PDF. XSL-FO has variables for data, but there is no data until it becomes a PDF.

Comment: That is incorrect. XSL FO has all the data and no variables. Daniel Haley is correct. While it may not be easy, it would be significantly easier to extract the data from XML (which XSL FO is) than attempting to parse the PDF.

Comment: The step from XML to PDF is a *lossy* step. You loose crucial information (data tags, hierarchy, paragraphs of text) and all you get back from parsing a PDF  is unstructured data: fonts, sizes, coordinates, fragments of text.

Comment: If (as you say above) you have an "XSL FO" (note the quotes) file with placeholders for data that is injected programmatically, then you do not have "XSL FO". You have a pseudo template that contains XSL FO markup, but it is not an XSL FO file. If they do not use traditional XML+XSL to get FO and you have no way to intercept the data or the resulting file with substiutions then you have a job ahead of you. You could use the XML area tree representation from FOP and try to use spatial information to extract the information. Slightly easier than trying from PDF.

Comment: Do you have access to and can you change the thing you are calling the XSL FO template? Maybe you can trick it and create something easier to parse. Can you post a sample of that XSL FO template showing the data substitution it tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the application to generate an XML with the data you need, and then hand that XML plus the XSL-FO template to the FOP renderer. If you can intercept the XML while FOP is running (before it finishes and deletes the XML), you're done.

If that fails: the XSL-FO template is an ordinary XSL file. You could try replacing its contents with an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). I don't know how FOP will handle this though.